# How to insert platform specific paths into a database in Java

Tags: java, file

I am working on an application that processes a large number of files placed in a directory. I want to insert the fully qualified path of each file that is processed by my application into the database. If a file that is already processed by the application is re-submitted for re-processing by the user, then I want to delete all the data processed for the file from the database by specifying the fully qualified path of the file and then proceed with the file as if it were a new file.

The problem that I am facing is that when I run the application through eclipse, the path name inserted into the database is as follows:-

```
   D:\Trunk\App\Source
```

Afer I concatenate the file name with its path (pathString + File.seperator + fileNameString) i.e, the fully qualified path inserted into the database is as follows

```
   D:\Trunk\App\Source/file1.txt
```

But if I create a jar for my application and run the jar by double clicking on the jar, the path name inserted into the database is as follows:-

```
   D:/Trunk/App/Source
```

After I concatenate the file name with its path (pathString + File.seperator + fileNameString) i.e, the fully qualified path inserted into the database is as follows

```
  D:/Trunk/App/Source/file1.txt
```

The application fails to delete the data for a file that is resubmitted for processing if the application is run by double clicking on the jar instead of running the application from eclipse. The query used for deleting is the same regardless of running the application from eclipse or by double clicking the jar

```
    delete from file_table where where file = 'D:\Trunk\App\Source/file1.txt'
```

Comment: cant you stick to one type of file separator? eg. convert all / to \ while inserting and while checking with the database

Comment: That could work. Although my application generates .csv report once it completes processing all the files. This report contains the path to each file in one of the columns. This brings us to the second problem that I am facing i.e, the paths displayed in the report should be platform specific to be more meaningful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert path to URI and store in database. Then recreate file from URI.

`String uriName = new File(path).toURI().toString()`

`String path = new File(new URI(uriName)).getAbsolutePath();`

Comment: This seems to work like a charm on Windows. I don't have enough space for a Linux partition on my computer to test this out on Linux. Will this work on Linux as well? Also, I tried out file.getAbsolutePath directly instead of using a URI and it seems to work this way as well. What advantage does the toURI method and the URI class provide in comparison to using file.getAbsolutePath directly

Comment: It works of unix. You can File.getCanonicalPath() instead. URI (URL is deprecated) always use format `file:/home/user/workspace/a.txt` with "/" - you do not need conversion to "\"

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I am using / as the separator and I am calling file.getAbsolutePath and it seems to work well on windows. Do I need to change file.getAbsolutePath to file.getCanonicalPath to be on the safer side?

Comment: I think not. Because in your case you remove "real" directory (if you create symbolic link)

Answer (score 2):

Just convert all `"\"` to `"/"` or vice versa for all file paths that you process.

Comment: Although this is a valid solution, I am looking for a more generic solution where I don't have to explicitly perform a replace all over my application.